# Change figure width from code chunks in PowerPoint

Tags: r, powerpoint, quarto

Figures produced by code chunks are placed to the right of the slide in PowerPoint, and the text is left. This is nice. But I can't modify the figure width. When I try to increase the figure width, the *figure height* **decreases** instead. Modifying the figure height works.

I think there must be some box / container created behind the scenes which I don't know how to specifically modify. Any ideas?

````
---
title: "test"
format: pptx
editor: visual
---

## Test
This is Iris. 

Iris was born in 1936.

Her father's name was Ronald 
```{r}
plot(iris)
```
````

#### Default output:

[image]

#### Changing figure width compresses the height

Tried with chunk option fig.width, or YAML option fig-width, here 15 inch.
[image]

#### Figure height works

[image]

Comment: I think that's because the image is inserted into a placeholder, i.e. the image is scaled to fit into the placeholder, e.g. when I add `fig-width: 20` via the YAML I get an image with width 50.8 cm aka 20 inches but it's scaled down to 28% of the original size so I end up with a width of 14,xx cm.

Comment: @stefan This is what I was thinking too. I've found a solution. It's a bit of a finicky one, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to change the powerpoint template used [as described here](https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html#powerpoint-templates). I found the description a bit difficult, so let me re-iterate in my own simpleton way.

1. First, create a template pptx file (e.g., via RStudio terminal):

> quarto pandoc -o template.pptx --print-default-data-file reference.pptx

This will create a file `template.pptx` in your working directory.

2. Second, in this file (template.pptx), change the default layout **in the master view**.

> Powerpoint menu: view - master - slide master

For this particular question, you need to change the layout of the *"Content with Caption"* slide.

3. Last, but not least, change the YAML header:

```
---
title: "test"
format: 
  pptx:
    reference-doc: template.pptx
editor: visual
---
```

(Needless to say, the file needs to be named like your template file in the working directory).

Result:

[image]

Comment: I think this is the way to go. Nice step-by-step guide for creating a custom template. (: